chkdsk "unspecified error" - how to speed up and when to give up?
I have a corrupted NFTS partition and have been trying to fix with CHKDSK (Windows 11) only to have the "unspecified error" at some moment. The thing is that CHKDSK is advancing in the filesystem fixing between runs, so there is hope that there will be a successful run at some point.
The log pattern for each run is:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is MMMMM.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
File record segment <NNNN> is unreadable.
...
<<repeat for many segments, most the same of the previous runs>>
...
  1036800 file records processed.
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 5.23 hours.
  9 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 1.13 milliseconds.
  774 bad file records processed.
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 2.27 hours.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
File record segment NNNN is unreadable.
...
<<repeat for some segments, typically *not* the same of previous runs>>
...
Deleting index entry FFFFF in index $I30 of file 13BF.
<<repeat for some files, typically *not* the same of previous runs>>
...
  522 reparse records processed.
Deleting index entry FFFFF in index $I30 of file 3944.
...
<<repeat for some files, *not* the same of previous runs>>
<<some of the files here were deleted in previous runs' Stage 2>>
...
Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 3.70 hours.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
Recovering orphaned file FFFF (3970) into directory file 3944.
...
<<repeat for some files, *not* the same of previous runs>>
<<some of the files here were deleted in previous runs' Stage 2>>
...
An unspecified error occurred (696e647863686b2e 21c3).

The first runs stopped with "unspecified error" in earlier stages, with distinct parameters.
I've tried with different options such as /offlinescanandfix, /b, /r, /x with similar behavior.
/forceofflinefix would be a nice option since it separates the scan and fixing phases but that gives me:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Insufficient storage available to create either the shadow copy storage file or other shadow copy data.
A snapshot error occured while scanning this drive. Run an offline scan and fix.

Anyone with the same experience? It would be great to be able to speed up chkdsk by skipping for instance Phase 1, which detects the same segments over and over - shouldn't chkdsk mark them as invalid and be able to run without checking them again?

Are you using online check (/scan) or offline check (/f)?

/scan results in Insufficient storage available to create either the shadow copy storage file or other shadow copy data. A snapshot error occured while scanning this drive. Run an offline scan and fix. Have been trying the offline options.
